# How do I edit content with a non-admin user?

Tags: user-management

I created a new user so that user can edit content

For example the user is Chelsea. I made it and I tried to give full access

So it's the same as admin. This is only for tests. I logged in with the Chelsea user and tried to edit the website banner. But it is disabled like this:

[image]

**Note** :

This is only for checking. the user that I entered is myself. I'm checking access viewers. because later I will give access rights to users based on their needs

So before I give them viewer access, I try it first

But I found this problem. New users who have already been granted access cannot edit the banner

How can I solve this problem?

I using sitecore version 8.2

Comment: This is a fairly basic level of configuration in Sitecore. You should _never_ give content editors Admin rights. I recommend you take a look at the Sitecore documentation on Security and Administration: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/security-and-administration.html

Comment: @Richard Seal Read my note. This is only for checking. later I will give access to the editor only to edit the banner

Answer (score 0):

As Richard said above roles and access rights are pretty standard Sitecore basics. However to elaborate a little more, what you should be looking to do is to assign users certain roles depending on what they need to do in Sitecore. Roles have access rights to do certain things.

Sitecore has a number of pre-defined roles which are listed and explained here: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/the-security-roles.html

For basic content editing you will probably want to give a user the following roles:

- Author
- Designer
- Client Publisher

Some of these roles are also members of other roles (e.g Sitecore Client Users which gives login access to Sitecore)

You may also want to consider giving more advanced users access to the 'Developer' role (if they need to do things like use package designed or access some tools from the Sitecore /admin page) or creating your own custom editor role which has some of these roles assigned to it for ease of management: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/create-and-set-up-a-role.html

You should also read up on inheritance of access rights: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/the-inheritance-access-right.html